# what's difference between setState and mobx setState

Tags: reactjs

soon I checked state after call setState in some method before re-render, I see state value hasn't changed because of rendered not followed yet. I'm following this concept so far..

However, when it comes to `Mobx` `action` methods in class based components, I see state has been changed before re-render.

Is there something difference in rendering when using mobx?

```js
  // functional component 
... 
 const [state, setState] = useState(false); 
 
 const init = () => {
   if(..some condition logic){
  console.log('check state before setState()', state) // false
  setState(true);
  console.log('check state after setState()', state) // false
  } 
 } 
 useEffect(() => {
    init(); 
  },[])
```

**using mobx**

```js
 //class based component 
 ... 
 @observable flag = false;
 
 @action 
 setFlag( bool ) {
   this.flag = bool;  
 }
 init(){
   if(... some condition logic) {
     console.log (this.flag) // false 
     setFlag(true); 
     console.log(this.flag) // true 
   } 
 } 
 componentDidMount() {
  init(); 
 }
```

Comment: In short, mobx meant to hold  the state but unlink `useState` which is "local" in the component's scope, mobx meant to hold more global state (maybe even the whole app's state). Because of this, when you want a child component to has the parents state, it's easy with mobx (because it's global) but with regular state, you have to propagate it through props (unless you have other approaches like context or HOC.